# Indentation within a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

this question is based on this other one: [Nested Loop Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591917/nested-loop-python)

One of the answer is

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(i):
        print(i, end='')
    print()
```

I don't understand why after the `print(i, end = ' ')` statement Python then runs the `print()` statement. In other words, since `print()` is not in the nested loop, shouldn't this code be only run after the nested `j` loop is completed?

Comment: Well yes... it does only run after the nested j loop is completed. Where's the issue?

Comment: Did you run this code to see what happens? Did you change the indentation to see what happens then?

Comment: The `print()` is there to print a newline each time after the inner loop is done.

Comment: I think it is so it prints one nested loop and then prints an empty line

Comment: What makes you think that the `print()` statement _doesn't_ only run after the `j` loop?

Comment: @Crawley: then you think wrong. Why would it print an empty line? It just ends the current line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **is** only run after the nested loop. Looking at the output from the post you referenced, the program starts with 1, prints one 1 without a newline, then exits the nested loop, then prints the newline. Then it enters the nested loop with 2, loops twice (prints a 2 without a newline, then prints a second two without a newline), then exits the loop and prints a newline.

Answer (score 0):

The print() is indented to be a part of the' i' for loop. So every time that 'i' for  block runs, the' j 'for happens THEN the print() takes the cursor to the next line

Answer (score 0):

> > The print() statement is executed after the nested j loop.
> >     It has been indented to make it a part of the outer loop i.

What print() statement is actually doing here?

> It is used to move the cursor to the next line after each row is printed.

Understand it like this:

for i in range(0,range1):

(indentation) for j in range(0,range2):

(indentation)(indentation) print(i, end='') //loop j ends

(indentation) print() //part of outer loop i