# What is the Python syntax for a general nested for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I am writing a program in Python that uses this nested for loop:

[image]

But I get this syntax error:

[image]

How should I rewrite this loop to avoid the error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question and copy-and-paste the code and error messages as text into your question. Thanks.

Comment: Also, add all relevant code. It looks like you want a [`while`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) loop there, but I can't say for sure: `while j >= i and j < 5:`

Comment: Welcome! 
Please write your code and error on the post and not by image.
You can read about nested loops here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591917/nested-loop-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite it to be like this:

```py
def update_grid():
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(i, 5):
            # do whatever you want with i and j
```

And here is a proof of concept of the code above:

```py
>>> for i in range(5):
...     for j in range(i, 5):
...             print((i, j))
... 
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 4)
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, that is how I ended up doing it. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkMizzi, if possible, please mark my answer as accepted.