# Find common elements and their frequency in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have multiple (~40) lists that contain dictionaries, that I would like to find

1. which are those list items (in this case dictionaries) that are common in all lists
2. how many times each unique item appears across all lists.

Some examples of the lists are:

```
a = [{'A': 0, 'B': 0},
     {'A': 0, 'C': 1},
     {'D': 1, 'C': 0},
     {'D': 1, 'E': 0}]

b = [{'A': 0},
     {'B': 0, 'C': 1},
     {'D': 1, 'C': 0},
     {'D': 1, 'E': 0}]

c = [{'C': 0},
     {'B': 1},
     {'D': 1, 'C': 0, 'E': 0},
     {'D': 1, 'E': 0}]
```

What I tried so far, it is the following code, but it returned values that were not common in all lists...

```
def flatten(map_groups):
    items = []
    for group in map_groups:
        items.extend(group)
    return items


def intersection(map_groups):
    unique = []
    items = flatten(map_groups)
    for item in items:
        if item not in unique and items.count(item) > 1:
            unique.append(item)
    return unique

all_lists = [a,b,c]
intersection(all_lists)
```

What I would expect to get as a result would be:

```
1. {'D': 1, 'E': 0} as a common item in all lists

2.   {'D': 1, 'E': 0}, 3   
     {'D': 1, 'C': 0}, 2
     {'A': 0, 'B': 0}, 1
     {'A': 0, 'C': 1}, 1
     {'A': 0}, 1
     {'B': 0, 'C': 1}, 1
     {'C': 0},
     {'B': 1},
     {'D': 1, 'C': 0, 'E': 0}
```

Comment: what do you mean by common dictionaries? common keys or ?

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Comment: 1) You don't need luck to solve it, just thinking :p 2) explain what are "common dicts" 3) show us what you have done so far

Comment: You mean a *dict* needs to appear in ALL lists to be considered? or just in more than one?... Is this part of a larger code or just an excercise? (important to define the structure of inputs and outputs)... have you tried to build a manual cache/counter?... Most of the time it helps if you provide the "would be result" of your sample data along with an explanation of how that result fulfills all rules

Comment: @HWSiew bad way to phrase it... I apologize. I meant finding the common list items. I have edited my question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count things, python comes with a nice class: [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Now the question is: What do you want to count?

For example, if you want to count the dictionaries that have the same keys and values, you can do something like this:

```
>>> count = Counter(tuple(sorted(x.items())) for x in a+b+c)
>>> count.most_common(3)
[((('C', 0), ('D', 1)), 2), ((('D', 1), ('E', 0)), 2), ((('A', 0), ('B', 0)), 1)]
```

The dictionaries here are converted to tuples with sorted items to make them comparable and hashable. Getting for example the 3 most common back as a list of dictionaries is also not too hard:

```
>>> [dict(x[0]) for x in count.most_common(3)]
[{'C': 0, 'D': 1}, {'D': 1, 'E': 0}, {'A': 0, 'B': 0}]
```

Comment: Unless OP intends to count the actual dictionaries, which are not hashable and thus not feasible to count with collections

Comment: That would make sense if the dictionaries are very large - but the example data provided seems like they are relatively simple and the conversion to tuples should not be a problem. In that case, I'd argue that expressive, easy to read code is more important than performance.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking for my second point. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [nested `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24591917/13552470):

```
a = [{'A': 0, 'B': 0},
     {'A': 0, 'C': 1},
     {'D': 1, 'C': 0},
     {'D': 1, 'E': 1}]

b = [{'A': 0},
     {'B': 0, 'C': 1},
     {'D': 1, 'C': 0},
     {'D': 1, 'E': 0}]

c = [{'C': 0},
     {'B': 1},
     {'D': 1, 'C': 0, 'E': 0},
     {'D': 1, 'E': 0}]

abc_list = [*a, *b, *c]
abc = list()

for d in abc_list:
    for i in abc:
        if d == i[0]:
            abc[abc.index(i)] = (d, i[1] + 1)
            continue
    abc.append((d, 1))

print(abc)
```

Output:

```
[({'A': 0, 'B': 0}, 1),
 ({'A': 0, 'C': 1}, 1),
 ({'D': 1, 'C': 0}, 2),
 ({'D': 1, 'E': 1}, 1),
 ({'A': 0}, 1),
 ({'B': 0, 'C': 1}, 1),
 ({'D': 1, 'E': 0}, 2),
 ({'C': 0}, 1),
 ({'B': 1}, 1),
 ({'D': 1, 'C': 0, 'E': 0}, 1)]
```

Explanation:

The line

```
[*a, *b, *c]
```

[unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50950690/13552470)s all the values in lists `a`, `b` and `c` into a single list, which \i named `abc_list`.

The [`continue`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8420705/13552470) statement where I put it means to directly continue to the next iteration of the inner `for` loop, without reaching `abc.append((d, 1))`.

The above output answers question 2. **For question 1**, we can use the built-in `max()` method on the `abc` list, with a custom key:

```
print(max(ABC, key=lambda x:x[1])[0])
```

Of course, it will only return one dictionary, `{'D': 1, 'C': 0}`. If you want to print out multiple dictionaries that appear the most frequently:

```
m = max(abc, key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
for d in abc:
    if d[1] == m:
      print(d[0])
```

Output:

```
{'D': 1, 'C': 0}
{'D': 1, 'E': 0}
```

Comment: How does this answer `which are those dictionaries that are common in all lists`?