# Merge nested lists keeping the column (elements at same index) together

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, multiple-columns

I have a lists of lists:

```
lst = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3]
]
```

How would I be able to add each column of the list to an empty list.
By column I mean, `lst[i][column]`, e.g. `1,1,1` then `2,2,2`, etc. and get a **new** list like this:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
```

So far I have tried:

```
pos = 0
column = 0
row = 0
i = 0
empty = []
while i < len(lst):
    empty.append(lst[i][0])
    i += 1
print(empty)
```

Comment: `[e for sl in zip(*lst) for e in sl]
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can use a [nested list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18072759/13552470):

```
lst = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3]
]

print([v[i] for i in range(len((lst[0]))) for v in lst])
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

---

The nested list comprehension above is the equivalent of this [nested `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24591917/13552470):

```
lst = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3]
]

arr = list()
for i in range(len((lst[0]))):
    for v in lst:
        arr.append(v[i])
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Finally, you can use the built-in [`zip()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13704860/13552470) method:

```
lst = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3]
]

print([j for i in zip(*lst) for j in i])
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a functional way to achieve this via using combination of [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) as:

```
from itertools import chain

my_list = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3]
]

new_list = list(chain(*zip(*my_list)))
```

where `new_list` will hold:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Refer below links to know more about these functions:

- [*`itertools.chain()`* document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)
- [*`zip()`* document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and really work the [star operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-a-function-call):

```
from itertools import chain

[*chain(*zip(*lst))]  
# or more classic:
# list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*lst)))
# [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

or use the transpositional pattern `zip(*...)` shown above in a simple nested comprehension:

```
[x for sub in zip(*lst) for x in sub]
# [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: for `chain.from_iterable()` +1 lol

Comment: One might note that `chain.from_iterable` is not really beneficial for most of these academic SO questions where you do consume the entire iterable anyway. Its real power is when used in a context where you might have some short-circuit logic (or the iterable is infinite) where `*` unnecessarily unpacks spurious elements or even runs out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3]
]
new_list = []
for i,j in enumerate(lst):
    new = lst[i]
    new_list.extend(new)

new_list = sorted(new_list)

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```