# How to create nested loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

In python I'm trying to write nested loops in one line. I've seen a lot of examples, but in all of them the inner iterable variable is different compared to the outer one. So in my case, it won't work. Here's my try:

```
my_list = [for ip in subnet for subnet in subnets]
```

where I'm getting:

```
Unresolved reference 'subnet'
```

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591917/nested-loop-python

Comment: @YUVI_1303 it seems you didn't read my question :)

Comment: `[ip for subnet in subnets for ip in subnet]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error, it should be

```
my_list = [ip for subnet in subnets for ip in subnet]
```

Comment: didn't work in this case: `[pool.apply_async(handle_ip, (ip,)) for ip in subnet for subnet in subnets]`

Comment: It's unintuitive, but you have to flip the loop conditions to ensure that the loop variables are declared in the proper order.  `[pool.apply_async(handle_ip, (ip,)) for subnet in subnets for ip in subnet]`

Comment: You're 100% right, edited answer above.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this

```
my_list = [[ip for ip in subnet] for subnet in subnets]
```

is a way to nest loops in list comprehension

Can check this too https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-list-comprehensions-in-python/

Comment: That inner comprehension should be `[ip for ip in subnet]`.  It doesn't make sense to start a list comprehension with `for`.

Comment: this *doesn't even compile*

Comment: @0x5453 sorry my mistake, i forgot to put ip at the start. I'm going to edit it.